# code to generate intraday data for a list of stock

Tags: python

not able to generate data for a group of stocks from csv file

i am able to generate data for single stock but when i am trying to generate for a list of stocks, code is not working

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
from datetime import timedelta

api_key1 = 'Key'
ts = TimeSeries(key=api_key1, output_format='pandas')

symbol = []

with open('D:\python_Study\Stock.csv') as f:  
    for line in f:
        symbol.append(line.strip())
f.close


print (symbol)

path_out ='D:\Data\intraday_data/'

i=0
while i<len(symbol):
    try:
        data, metadata = ts.get_intraday(symbol = "NSE:"+symbol[i], interval = '1min', outputsize = 'full')
        data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)
        data.index = data.index + timedelta(hours = 9, minutes = 31)
        data.rename(columns = {'1. open':'open', '2. high': 'high', '3. low': 'low', '4. close':'close', '5. volume': 'volume'}, inplace = True)
        data['symbol'] = symbol[i]
        data.index.rename('datetime', inplace = True)      
        data.insert(0,'Symbol',symbol[i])

        df.to_csv(path_out+symbol[i]+'.csv')
        if i == 0:
            data.to_csv(path_out+symbol[i]+'.csv')
            print (i, symbol[i],'has data stored to csv file')
        else:
                data.to_csv(path_out+symbol[i]+'.csv',header=True)
                print (i, symbol[i],'has data stored to csv file')
    except:
        print("No information for ticker # and symbol:")
        print (i,symbol[i])
        i=i+1
        continue
        i=i+1
```

Comment: "code is not working" does not constitute a valid problem statement

Answer (score 0):

You are missing try for the except block. Also, you are incrementing i in the except block (unless the formatting got messed up during the post).